# Как сделать чтобы вызывался Spinner из ActionBara?

Tags: android

Как сделать чтобы вызывался Spinner из ActionBara?

После нажатия на иконку.Так как в стандартном spinner там просто треугольник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду как программно вызвать открытие спиннера, то попробуйте так:

```
// Open the Spinner...
mSpenner.performClick();
```

Comment: Нет) Я хочу установить в акшен бар кнопку в виде search. А по нажатии на нее должен открыться обычный Spinner. Просто Сам по себе Spinner имеет строку и справа треугольник. Вот я и хотел узнать. Можно ли заменить это все на иконку search допустим

Comment: Ну вообще иконку треугольника можно заменить, на сколько я знаю. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028202/android-add-arrow-image-to-spinner). А вообще, если не секрет, зачем такая конструкция?

Comment: В гугле видел просто. Вот решил сделать. А гугл же как всегда не рассказывает как делать

Comment: А можно увидеть изображение?